How do I filter Pod restarts per hour for Error condition only?
Thank you for the assistance with PromQL for Pod restarts last hour by Namespace - much appreciated.
Now I'm looking to filter results by only restarts caused by an error condition.  I know we have commands such as 'kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason' with Reasons such as 'Error' and 'OOMKilled'
Ideally I'd like to join some fields from 'kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason' with 'kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total' .  I could do this no problem if it was SQL.  But, I'm still getting my brain around PromQL.
I appreciate any inputs from the community on how I can filter my pod restart total to include only Error and OOMKilled conditions.
Thanks.

You can use the on vector matching operator and a group_left group modifier. A query like this:
kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total
  * on (pod, container) group_left (reason) 
(kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason)

allows to have the value of the kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total metric with the additional label reason (specified in the group_left) from kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason. Here you can see an example in play.grafana.org.

Note: the example in the play.grafana.org example is using the kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason metric instead of kube_pod_container_status_terminated_reason but the principle is the same.

